# unable to resolve an issue with Cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I executed the below query and deleted all relations

```
START n=node:search('username:donna') 
MATCH n-[rel18?:STATUS]->(n18)-[rel19?:NEXT*1..]->(n19) 
WITH n, rel18, n18, rel19, n19 
FOREACH(rel IN rel19: DELETE rel) 
DELETE n19, n18, rel18;
```

Result: 6 relations and 6 nodes got deleted.

Now when I try to execute the same query again, I get an error Unknown identifier `rel19`

In fact even the below query gives the same error Unknown identifier `rel19`

```
START n=node:search('username:donna') 
MATCH n-[rel18?:STATUS]->(n18)-[rel19?:NEXT*1..]->(n19) 
RETURN n.username, rel18, n18, rel19, n19;
```

My domain model is same as this example, 
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypher-cookbook-newsfeed.html

I am trying to implement delete for the same.

Also the above delete query (1st query) will be part of a bigger query appended using the WITH clause. So there will be cases when that particular user might not have any STATUS and NEXT relations but still the whole query should execute successfully. Can you please help in modifying the query so that query runs fine in all cases.

Thanks,
Pavan

Answer (score 0):

`[rel19?:NEXT*1..]->(n19)`  means an optional relationship, thus the match statement on this may or may not contain this path. if it will not contain this path, it will not parse it further to the return clause. than the return clause will output an error on identifier which does not exists. i suggest to put a WHERE condition before RETURN like this;

```
START n=node:search('username:donna')
MATCH n-[rel18?:STATUS]->(n18)-[rel19?:NEXT*1..]->(n19)
WITH n, rel18, n18, rel19, n19 
WHERE n--n18
DELETE n19, n18, rel18
WITH rel19, n19 
WHERE ()-[rel19:]-n19
DELETE n19
WITH rel19
FOREACH(rel IN rel19: DELETE rel)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ulkas but i am still facing the same issue.